# How can I recognize an ASP.NET Core project in a Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, vsix

In my Visual Studio Package, I look at each project in the solution and I need to determine what kind of project it is.

Historically I use technique something like the one described by Carlos Quintero [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007016.aspx) to get the project GUIDs and look for specific GUIDs in the list.

For ASP.NET Core projects, I have looked for

```
AspNetCore:  "{8BB2217D-0F2D-49D1-97BC-3654ED321F3B}"
AspNetCore2: "{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}"
```

This will probably still work, if the project uses an old-style project file.

However, it does not work if the new Visual Studio Project system is used.

This is the project file that I am currently using:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="App_GlobalResources\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="App_GlobalResources\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Controllers\App_LocalResources\HomeController.resx.en.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Controllers\HomeController.en.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Controllers\HomeController.nl.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Controllers\HomeController.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Controllers\StudentController.en.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Models\Student.en.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Views\Home\About.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Views\Home\Contact.en.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Views\Home\Index.en.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Views\Home\Index.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As you can see, it does not contain the project GUIDs.

Using the technique described in [How to detect whether a project is a CPS project](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/automation/detect_whether_a_project_is_a_CPS_project.md#how-to-detect-whether-a-project-is-a-cps-project), I can detect that it is a CPS (Common Project System) project.

Using the technique described in [Finding CPS in a VS project](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/automation/finding_CPS_in_a_VS_project.md#finding-cps-in-a-vs-project), I am able to get hold of the "unconfigured project", and I could also get the "configured project" (although I'm not sure I understand what "unconfigured" and "configured" mean in this context).

At this point I am stuck. I can't figure out how to determine if it is an ASP.NET Core project.

The best bet is probably to get the **TargetFramework** attribute, which is **netcoreapp2.0**. Is there any way that to get the **TargetFramework** attribute from the CPS project object?

Or am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for the TargetFrameworkMoniker:

```
    public static bool IsNetCore2(this Project project)
    {
        return project.Properties.Item("TargetFrameworkMoniker").Value.ToString().Contains(".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.");
    }
```

https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/blob/master/src/GUI/EFCorePowerTools/Extensions/ProjectExtensions.cs#L75

To detect ASP.NET Core, I think you will have to parse the csproj file:
and look for **Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"**

Comment: Thanks Erik, that fixes my immediate problem. It also means I don't need to reference the VCProjectEngine package. It would still be interesting to know if it is possible to access the Sdk Attribute without parsing the file.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between .NET Core and ASP.NET Core??

Comment: Possibly I do not need to. My knowledge of .NET Core is quite limited. My package adds localization support to projects. For ASP.NET Core projects it adds support using the IStringLocalizer method. The documentation that I have seen always relates to ASP.NET Core, but it seems quite likely that it would be supported by other .NET Core projects.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good solution is to use the MsBuild API, in the nuget package **Microsoft.Build**.

If you have the ENVDte.Project object, you can get the path to the project file using the FullName property.

Then you can access the Sdk property as follows:

```
void foo ( ENVDte.Project prj )
{
  var MsBuildProject = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project ( prj.FullName ) ;
  
  if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty ( MsBuildProject.Xml.Sdk ) )
  {
    // Not .NET core
  }
  else if ( MsBuildProject.Xml.Sdk == "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" )
  {
    // ASP.NET core
  }
  else if ( MsBuildProject.Xml.Sdk == "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop" )
  {
    // .NET core desktop app
  }
}
```

This is really just the same as parsing the project file and looking for Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web", as Eric already suggested, but I prefer to use an API if possible.

If you are looking for other details about the project, there is a lot more information in the MsBuild project object, for example in the collection AllEvaluatedItems or the collection AllEvaluatedProperties.